# Import specific items from module file in Python, while ignoring other imports in same module file?

Tags: python, python-import

Let's say I have this file as `lib_my.py`:

```py
import smbus

main_array = [1, 10, 20, 100]
```

Now, I run this usually on Raspberry Pi Raspbian, where I have the `smbus` package.

However, now for a test, I'd like to import `main_array` on Windows, where I do not have `smbus` (and I'm not sure it can be installed either) - and this is the result:

```
$ python3
Python 3.9.11 (main, Mar 18 2022, 16:54:01)  [GCC 11.2.0 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> from lib_my import main_array

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:/msys64/tmp/lib_my.py", line 1, in <module>
    import smbus
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'smbus'
>>>
```

So, even if `main_array` is just a primitive (list of integers), Python still tries to import the *whole* library first, and as expected, chokes on `import smbus`.

Is there a way to instruct Python, to import *only* the requested item (primitive object, class, function), ignoring other imports in the same file (that are otherwise unrelated to the imported item)?

Comment: Probably not, but you could put a file `smbus.py` in the current directory, so that it would be imported instead of the actual library. Of course, the script's usage of the module will break then

Comment: Thanks @forcebru - that actually looks like it might work in my case!